# Timed animated gif display

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, animated-gif

Noob Alert.....

I have searched previous questions and can not find this specific request.

For my Art project I have created an animated gif and want it to display/run my animated gif for **just one hour per day** on the website I have created for my other projects.

I have this script which is very similar but I need to automate the display (for one hour each day) and not on click or stepped. I can get rid of these stages but not sure on what to replace them with.

JavaScript Animation

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     <!--
        var imgObj = null;
        var animate ;

        function init(){
           imgObj = document.getElementById('myImage');
           imgObj.style.position= 'relative'; 
           imgObj.style.left = '0px'; 
        }

        function moveRight(){
           imgObj.style.left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left) + 10 + 'px';
           animate = setTimeout(moveRight,20); // call moveRight in 20msec
        }

        function stop(){
           clearTimeout(animate);
           imgObj.style.left = '0px'; 
        }

        window.onload =init;
     //-->
  </script>
```

Thank you in advance.....

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here.. Is the problem the time detection?

Comment: Yes, I guess so. I need the gif to display for one hour in each 24.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first thing to notice is that you'll have to check the current time every now and then, to check if we're at that certain hour you want to show the animation.

Let's take as example: between 13h and 14h (1pm and 2pm)- from now on I'll use the 24h notation.

We can use an `interval` to check if it's past 13h already. We choose the precision ourselves. For the sake of the example, let's say that we check every 5 minutes:

```
//Note: we could say "300000" immediately instead, but with the calculation, we can easily change it when we want to.
var gifInterval = setInterval(function() {canWeAnimateYet ();}, 5 * 60 * 1000);
```

So, we got an interval that will check every 5 minutes. Now we need a `flag` (or `bool`) to see if the animation should run or not...

```
var animateThatGif = false;
```

And now.. We need the function to check the time:

```
var canWeAnimateYet = function() {
    //Checks here.
}
```

On that function, we need to check the currenttime. If it's past 13 but before 14h, we need to put our flag to `true`, otherwise it stays `false`.

```
var canWeAnimateYet = function() {

     //Get current time
     //Note: "new Date()" will always return current time and date.
     var time = new Date();

     //Note: getHours() returns the hour of the day (between 0 and 23 included). Always in 24h-notation.
     if (time.getHours() >= 13 && time.getHours < 14)
        animateThatGif = true;
     else
        animateThatGif = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.....that helped and worked a treat. Appreciate you taking the time and trouble.. Regards

Comment: @giveimtamongo if it helped you, please consider up voting it and marking  it as answer :)